# Hows to update Property in Embedded class using JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have bean classr FolderStructure 
with some annotation like below. I want to update some property in embedded class( nodeId in FolderStructureCompositeKey class). hows to achieve that?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PROGRAM_STRUCTURE", schema = "PROGRAM")
public class FolderStructure implements Serializable, BaseDomain{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2984032007505132468L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private FolderStructureCompositeKey pk;

    @Transient
    private Integer nodeID;

    @Transient
    private Integer parentID;

    @Column(name = "CHILD_COUNT")
    private Integer childCount;

    @Column(name = "OBJECT_TYPE")
    private String type;

    public FolderStructure(){

    }

    public FolderStructure(Integer nodeID, Integer parentID, Integer childCount, String type) {
        this.pk = new FolderStructureCompositeKey(nodeID, parentID);
        this.nodeID = nodeID;
        this.parentID = parentID;
        this.childCount = childCount;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Integer getNodeID() {
        return nodeID;
    }

    public void setNodeID(Integer nodeID) {
        createPK();
        this.nodeID = nodeID;
    }

    public Integer getParentID() {
        return parentID;
    }

    public void setParentID(Integer parentID) {
        createPK();
        this.parentID = parentID;
    }

    public Integer getChildCount() {
        return childCount;
    }

    public void setChildCount(Integer childCount) {
        this.childCount = childCount;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public FolderStructureCompositeKey getPk(){
        return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(FolderStructureCompositeKey pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FolderStructure [folderStructureCompositeKey=" + pk + ", nodeID=" + nodeID
                + ", parentID=" + parentID + ", childCount=" + childCount + ", type=" + type + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public void createPK() {
        if (pk == null) {
            pk = new FolderStructureCompositeKey();
        }

    }
}
```

And I have embedded class like this.

```
@Embeddable
public class FolderStructureCompositeKey implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4049555022783005378L;

    @Column(name = "OBJECT_ID")
    private Integer nodeID;

    @Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private Integer parentID;

    public FolderStructureCompositeKey() {
    }

    public FolderStructureCompositeKey(Integer nodeID, Integer parentID) {
        this.nodeID = nodeID;
        this.parentID = parentID;
    }

    public Integer getNodeID() {
        return nodeID;
    }

    public void setNodeID(Integer nodeID) {
        this.nodeID = nodeID;
    }

    public Integer getParentID() {
        return parentID;
    }

    public void setParentID(Integer parentID) {
        this.parentID = parentID;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FolderStructureCompositeKey [nodeID=" + nodeID
                + ", parentID=" + parentID + "]";
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the error you get when updating the `nodeID` field?

Comment: Something like this **Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [parentID] on this ManagedType [com.indivara.pm.beans.FolderStructure]**

Comment: Also post how you update/save an entity of type `FolderStructure ` and how you set fields.